# Codeigniter URL requires index.php in live while everything is good in localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, mod-rewrite

I have setup tens of CI projects in live but never got this issue before. I uploaded the site in live (/demo) but when I visit "www.example.com/demo", a blank screen is what I get. There's no error in error log.

The .htaccess I have using is no doubt working as it's the same for all projects that I have uploaded live.

Here is how its written:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /demo/

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Working good in my previous projects.

I have made in cofig/config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'; // tried REQUEST_URI too not working...
```

I think its a server issue? The mod_rewrite is enabled too.

Comment: Is your live server windows?

Comment: @kumar_v : No.. its linux..

Comment: did you try `query_string` in `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';`?

Comment: yes.. that i've mentioned in my question already.. not working :(

Comment: i said add query_string like $config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';

Comment: nop not working.. what does it do?

Comment: Can we see your Apache vhost definition? You need to ensure `AllowOverride` is set correctly - `All` will do it.

Comment: Enable mod_rewrite function in apache server